# Creating map book series with blank pages between maps using ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, map-book

I am looking to create a series of maps each one highlighting the camping pitch. I would like to put the number of the pitch highlighted on either page before or after to allow duplex printing of map on one side and pitch number on the other side.

Is this possible using ArcMap with or without python?

See image of camping pitches:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using ArcMap you could use data driven pages without Python by setting up a block of grids in an empty region of space. Add these grids to your existing grid feature class. Then renumber each grid to incorporate the empty page you desire. For example page 2 could be your page one indicator.

Alternatively using Python you can simply slide the data frame off the layout in between page extracts.